# Can't retrieve posts from facebook public page via facebook API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Yesterday on the Facebook Graph API tool I could create an access_token without having to own an App then get posts/publications via `{page-id}/posts` or `{page-id}/feed`.

Today, first thing when I arrive on the Facebook Graph API tool is that I have to create an application to have access then after creating it with the same operation than before it returns me an error like this

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "(#10) To use 'Page Public Content Access', your use of this endpoint must be reviewed and approved by Facebook. To submit this 'Page Public Content Access' feature for review please read our documentation on reviewable features: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review.",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 10,
        "fbtrace_id": "FJ52hd03hq"
    },
    "__debug__": {}
}
```

Then I went see someone owning a verified application so I can try with an access_token generated with his application. The result is the same.

Anyone facing the same problem ? Did I missed something ?

Comment: Yesterday you could use one of Facebooks apps in the Graph API tool. They announced yesterday that that is not possible anymore.

Comment: You were never actually supposed to use the Graph API Explorer’s own app id for your requests to get real data for actual live use; that is a test tool only.

Comment: So indeed @CBroe I was using "Graph API Explorer" App which was provided by facebook. I actually started discovering/using facebook graph api 4 days ago.  
Now that I understood that Facebook actually removed that App the only question remaining is "Why do I can't get posts from public page using a verified App to generate my access token ?"